# Using the diff function in a for loop

Tags: r, loops, dataframe, difference

I have a dataframe that I would like to generate columns that have the differences between the ones before it. Ie there's a new column with column 1 - column 2, the next is column 2 - column 3, etc.. I've written out the code (~pseudocode?) but I'm not entirely sure how to format it correctly. This is going to be a pipeline for different documents, so I can't hardcode the column names nor number. I would also like this loop to generate a new column with the header having the names of the columns it subtracted.

My data:

```
     Line_1    Line_2    Line_3    Line_4    Line_5    Line_6    Line_7
1         NA        NA        NA        NA        NA 0.0000000        NA
2  0.4054731 0.3193632 0.2667026 0.8494675 0.2394639 0.2936054 0.2453124
3  0.4048527 0.3195507 0.2693250 0.8664931 0.2380499 0.2931895 0.2437657
4  0.4041760 0.3226145 0.2731347 0.8756971 0.2338797 0.2876017 0.2432391
5  0.4079322 0.3264623 0.2750645 0.8770746 0.2273580 0.2866682 0.2476563
```

My "code":

```
for (n in 1:ncol(tempDF2)) {
    sub <- diff(n, lag = 1, differences = 1)
    name <- paste0(n, " - ", n+1)
    tempDF2$name <- sub
}
```

How can I get this to work? I'm open to sapply, etc. alternatives to a loop too.

Comment: Are you doing the difference between Line_2 - Line_1, Line_3 - Line_2, etc. in that `tempDF2[paste0(names(tempDF2)[-ncol(tempDF2)], "_n+1")] <- tempDF2[-1] - tempDF2[-ncol(tempDF2)]`

Comment: @akrun Right - I got the columns switched in my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `rowDiffs` from the `matrixStats` package and invert the differences:

```r
library(matrixStats)
df <- structure(list(Line_1 = c(NA, 0.4054731, 0.4048527, 0.404176, 
                                0.4079322), Line_2 = c(NA, 0.3193632, 0.3195507, 0.3226145, 0.3264623
                                ), Line_3 = c(NA, 0.2667026, 0.269325, 0.2731347, 0.2750645), 
                     Line_4 = c(NA, 0.8494675, 0.8664931, 0.8756971, 0.8770746
                     ), Line_5 = c(NA, 0.2394639, 0.2380499, 0.2338797, 0.227358
                     ), Line_6 = c(NA, 0.2936054, 0.2931895, 0.2876017, 0.2866682
                     ), Line_7 = c(0, 0.2453124, 0.2437657, 0.2432391, 0.2476563
                     )), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L))

-rowDiffs(as.matrix(df))
#>           [,1]      [,2]       [,3]      [,4]       [,5]      [,6]
#> [1,]        NA        NA         NA        NA         NA        NA
#> [2,] 0.0861099 0.0526606 -0.5827649 0.6100036 -0.0541415 0.0482930
#> [3,] 0.0853020 0.0502257 -0.5971681 0.6284432 -0.0551396 0.0494238
#> [4,] 0.0815615 0.0494798 -0.6025624 0.6418174 -0.0537220 0.0443626
#> [5,] 0.0814699 0.0513978 -0.6020101 0.6497166 -0.0593102 0.0390119
```

**Edit:**

If, contrary to your question, you want the differences of Line_2 - Line_1, etc., then it would be:

```r
setNames(data.frame(rowDiffs(as.matrix(df))), 
         paste0(colnames(df)[-1], "-", colnames(df)[-ncol(df)]))
#>   Line_2-Line_1 Line_3-Line_2 Line_4-Line_3 Line_5-Line_4 Line_6-Line_5
#> 1            NA            NA            NA            NA            NA
#> 2    -0.0861099    -0.0526606     0.5827649    -0.6100036     0.0541415
#> 3    -0.0853020    -0.0502257     0.5971681    -0.6284432     0.0551396
#> 4    -0.0815615    -0.0494798     0.6025624    -0.6418174     0.0537220
#> 5    -0.0814699    -0.0513978     0.6020101    -0.6497166     0.0593102
#>   Line_7-Line_6
#> 1            NA
#> 2    -0.0482930
#> 3    -0.0494238
#> 4    -0.0443626
#> 5    -0.0390119
```

<sup>Created on 2020-07-01 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Awesome! Any way to automate the headings?

Comment: Maybe: `setNames(data.frame(-rowDiffs(as.matrix(df))), paste0(colnames(df)[-ncol(df)], "-", colnames(df)[2:ncol(df)]))`

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this exactly what you're looking for, but the following function would calculate the difference between column 1 to column *n* sequentially. This will only work for data frames with numeric columns obviously. You can get a lot fancier with `dplyr` and dynamic variable naming (i.e. `enquo()`) but this might get you going in the right direction.

```
diff_cols <- function(dat) {
    list <- names(dat)
    col <- list()
    nam <- vector()
    for(i in 1:(ncol(dat)-1)) {
      col[[i]] <- dat[,i]-dat[,i+1] 
      nam[i] <- paste0(list[i], "-" ,list[i+1])
    }

  df <- as.data.frame(do.call(cbind, col))
  colnames(df) <- nam 
  return(df)
}
dat <- select_if(iris, is.numeric)
diff_cols(dat)
```

Answer (score 0):

In `base R`, we can do this by taking the difference of equally sized data.frames (by removing the first and last column)

```
out <- tempDF2[-ncol(tempDF2)] - tempDF2[-1]
names(out) <- paste0(names(tempDF2)[-1], "-", names(tempDF2)[-ncol(tempDF2)]) 


out
#  Line_2-Line_1 Line_3-Line_2 Line_4-Line_3 Line_5-Line_4 Line_6-Line_5 Line_7-Line_6
#1            NA            NA            NA            NA            NA            NA
#2     0.0861099     0.0526606    -0.5827649     0.6100036    -0.0541415     0.0482930
#3     0.0853020     0.0502257    -0.5971681     0.6284432    -0.0551396     0.0494238
#4     0.0815615     0.0494798    -0.6025624     0.6418174    -0.0537220     0.0443626
#5     0.0814699     0.0513978    -0.6020101     0.6497166    -0.0593102     0.0390119
```

#### data

```
tempDF2 <- structure(list(Line_1 = c(NA, 0.4054731, 0.4048527, 0.404176, 
0.4079322), Line_2 = c(NA, 0.3193632, 0.3195507, 0.3226145, 0.3264623
), Line_3 = c(NA, 0.2667026, 0.269325, 0.2731347, 0.2750645), 
    Line_4 = c(NA, 0.8494675, 0.8664931, 0.8756971, 0.8770746
    ), Line_5 = c(NA, 0.2394639, 0.2380499, 0.2338797, 0.227358
    ), Line_6 = c(NA, 0.2936054, 0.2931895, 0.2876017, 0.2866682
    ), Line_7 = c(0, 0.2453124, 0.2437657, 0.2432391, 0.2476563
    )), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L))
```